# Cracked joist problem

Tags: framing

I have cracked joists on the basement ceiling. 2x10x14 16" on center. There is a wall running parallel with the joist that has another floor above that. 
Should the joist have been doubled or tripled when built? Is there a code for that?

Comment: We're going to need more information, Jim. A photo would be ideal. Wood cracks. It doesn't usually mean there's a problem.

Comment: In my situation (https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/154900/how-to-fix-cracked-roof-joist) I think I had a bad joist.   In your situation with multiple cracked joists in a basement, I'd worry its a foundation issue.    I'd ask a structural engineer for their opinion and get an estimate too.

Comment: Without a photo we have no idea. What you are concerned about may be normal , it could be a failure but no one can say without at least a photo.

Comment: One broken joist isn't going to make the house collapse.  If it was load-bearing it'd likely be double up at the very least.  I've had to fix a few cracked ones in my basement (80yr old house).    Get a new 2x10 and sister it against the damaged one (nail it together side by side).  I don't know if there's a specific code for it, but I go about 2' beyond the crack in either direction at a minimum if I can. In one cause, I used a floor jack to level the broken joist back to where it should be before nailing in the sister beam to it.